# Generate a sine signal with time dependent frequency in C

Tags: c, arm, embedded, microcontroller

I want to generate a sine signal with a time dependent frequency that varies periodically between `fmin` and `fmax` with a frequency `f0` in C. Mathematically, this can be described by

```
y(t)=1/2*(1+sin(2*Pi*(fmin*t + (fmax-fmin)*1/2*(t - 1/2/Pi/f0*cos(2*Pi*f0*t) + 1/2/Pi/f0))))
```

Because I want to use this on a microcontroller, I want to reduce the use of floating-point numbers in order to save memory and increase performance.

This is also a reason why I cannot use the standard sine function. To calculate the sine function, I approximate it with a parabola. Therefore, I use the following code:

Input range [0R 2πR] mapped to [0 to 1024].

Output range [-1.0 1.0] mapped to [-512 512].

```
int_fast16_t sin_bam(int angle_bam) {
  angle_bam %= 1024;
  if (angle_bam < 0)
    angle_bam += 1024;
  uint_fast16_t sub_angle = angle_bam % (1024u / 2);
  int_fast16_t sn = (uint32_t) (sub_angle*(1024/2 - sub_angle) / 128);
  if (angle_bam & 512) {
    sn = -sn;
  }
  return sn;
}
```

My first approach to implement the signal above was

```
y(i) = sin_bam(fmin*i+(fmax-fmin)*(i-2/f0*sin_bam((int) (f0*i+1024/4))+1024/f0))+512.
```

For values of approximately `f0 >= 1`, this works well, but for smaller values my code seems to break, e.g. for `f0 = 0.1` the generated signal becomes very "unsmooth" each time it reaches a frequency minimum.

Here a sample output:

[image]

I assume that the problem could be the integer implementation of the sine function as for `f0 = 0.1` it reads

```
sin_bam((int) (0.1*i+1024/4)).
```

That means, for example for values of i between 0 and 9, sin_bam((int) (0.1*i+1024/4)) delivers the same output.

My first idea to solve this issue was to increase the angular resolution of the sine function, but unfortunately this didn't help.

Is there any logical error in my algorithm or does anybody have a better idea to implement this?

Comment: Do you have 16 or 32 bit `int`?

Comment: What type are `fmin,fmax,i`?

Comment: In `y(i)`, drop the `(int)` and change `sin_bam(...)` to `sin_bam(lrint(...))` in 2 places to see if the "jaggies" disappear.

Comment: I have 32 bit `int`. The variables `fmin` and `fmax` are `float` and `i` is `int`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'll try that.

Comment: Unfortunately, `lrint()` couldn't solve the problem. The "jaggies" are still there.

Comment: 1) If `for (i=0; i<= 1024; i++) sin_bam(i)` does not cause "jaggies" the problem is in `fmin*i+(fmax-fmin)*(i-2/f0*sin_bam((int) (f0*i+1024/4))+1024/f0)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162117/discussion-between-chux-and-peter123).

Comment: it seems like you are just asking the same question over and over again.  you need fixed point, you should only need a table to cover 1/4th of a sine wave and you manipulate from there, covers all of your questions yes?   you can prototype this on your development machine dont have to run it on the mcu other than a final size/performance test.

Comment: that or you are simply asking for more than a cortex-m0 can provide and need to move up to a cortex-m4 or m7 or a a full sized ARM.

Comment: have you looked at books like hackers delight?  That one doesnt cover sin and cos directly but you can get a feel for how to get out of the pure math mode into what can be implemented on a fixed point machine and some performance improvements on that.

Comment: Here is how it could be done. Reserve a part of memory for the sine samples, and to spare some development effort, do it for the whole period. Use sufficient number of samples, for example 2048. Now, you are simply going to have a counter that will represent the index of the sample within the sine. for each next sample, you will use the frequency that you want to generate to calculate the step of the sample: how much your index has to jump over. At the end of the sine, you will simply use the modulo 2048 to wrap the index to the beginning of the sine. I hope that this helps.

Comment: VladP is describing a lookup-table based Direct Digital Synthesizer, see for another example https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/330159/correct-note-frequency-for-stm32-based-midi-synth   This method is well suited to microcontrollers like a Cortex M0; it would appear you'll need to use it twice, once to generate the modulating signal and again to generate the modulated signal.